# How to add a class that autoloads in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I created a custom class named StatusLib.php in the app/library folder.

**StatusLib.php**

```php
namespace App\library;

class StatusLib
{
    CONST SUCCESS = '100';
    CONST SUCCESSWITHMESSAGE = '101';
}
```

I can call this status .

```
StatusLib::SUCCESS
```

When I add this following use code in the controller.

```
use app\library\StatusLib;
```

How can I add this StatusLib class in autoload and access from anywhere in the project?

Comment: Is the `StatusLib` class in a directory called `library` or `Library`?

Comment: StatusLib class is inside library directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces are case-sensitive.

In your `StatusLib` class  you have `App\library;`, however, in your controller you've used `app\library` -- these are not the same.

Change your `use` statement in your controller to  be:

```
use App\library\StatusLib;
```

You may also need to run:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

---

Just FYI, Laravel comes with the `app` directory already set up for autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` file, after the classmap array, add a `psr-0`:

```
"autoload" :{
    "classmap": [
         ...
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "library": "app/"
    }
}
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

where do you want to use it?
it will be automatically autoloaded because `app` folder is loaded in `composer.json`
here:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
   },
```

Comment: or if you want to make your namespace just `Library` you will make like this:
         `"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
         "Library": "app/library/"
    },
   },`

Comment: after that run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: so everywhere should i add 'use app\library\StatusLib' ?